# timedelta convert to time or int and store it in GAE (python) datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

It looks like this has been covered somewhat in other questions, but I'm still fairly confused on how to actually do this. My lack of experience isn't helping much with that.

I have two DateTimeProperties - StartTime and EndTime. I'm subtracting StartTime from EndTime to get the Duration. From my previous question (thank you to all that answered!) it looks like this operation is producing a timedelta.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to store timedelta directly in the GAE datastore, so this means I need to convert it either to an int in milliseconds, to a float in seconds or to time.

I will need to do other calculations on this later as well, such as figuring out avg. duration. Based on that, int seems to make the most sense to me right now.

What's the best way to do this or is there a tutorial I can play with?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make this as easy as possible to work with, there's two steps: Converting the timedelta to an int or a float, and storing it in the datastore. First things first, converting a timedelta to a microtime:

```
def timedelta_to_microtime(td):
  return td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 86400) * 1000000
```

You don't have to do the conversion yourself, though - you can define a custom datastore property, which will allow you to store timedeltas directly to your model:

```
class TimeDeltaProperty(db.Property):
  def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
    value = self.__get__(model_instance, model_instance.__class__)
    if value is not None:
      return timedelta_to_microtime(value)

  def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
    if value is not None:
      return datetime.timedelta(microseconds=value)
```

Now you can use this property like any other:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
  td = TimeDeltaProperty(required=True)

entity = MyModel(td=datetime.datetime.now()-some_datetime)
key = entity.put()

entity = db.get(key)
print entity.td
```

Comment: So is this the right way to make it into milliseconds?   event_record.Duration = int((delta.microseconds + (delta.seconds + delta.days * 86400) * 1000000)/1000)

Comment: I think your `TimeDeltaProperty` needs to define a `data_type` too. 

Second, I'm not sure what your `__get__` does, but the article on extending datastore properties suggests `super(TimeDeltaProperty, self).get_value_for_datastore(model_instance)`

Comment: @Sologoub Nearly - just remove the /1000 and delete 4 zeroes from the multiplier. :)

@Noio data_type isn't required - and nor is __get__ - the default getter and setter just store and retrieve the value as-is.

Comment: You sure? Cause I'm first converting to microseconds, then adding the microseconds from delta to converted seconds and days and then converting to milliseconds.

Comment: @Sologoub How about delta.microseconds / 1000 + (delta.seconds + delta.days * 86400) * 1000

Comment: That works too :)

Also, found this very helpful in creating datetime.time out of timedelta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764184/python-how-do-i-get-time-from-a-datetime-timedelta-object

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to store it as a `datetime` (which I agree is a good idea), I'd extend the `DateTimeProperty` - then you get various bits of parsing and validation for free.

Also, storing as `timedelta` as a `datetime` can be much easier than the other methods given here, by storing it as a datetime some distance from a reference datetime, such that the difference represents the timedelta. This is really easy thanks to the operator overloading the datetime module gives us.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from google.appengine.ext import db

class TimeDeltaProperty(db.DateTimeProperty):
    # Use a reference datetime half way between the min and max possible
    # datetimes, so that we can support both +ve and -ve timedeltas
    ref_datetime = (datetime.max - datetime.min) / 2 + datetime.min

    def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
        # Get the timedelta instance assigned to this property
        td = super(TimeDeltaProperty, self).get_value_for_datastore(model_instance)
        if td is not None:
            # datetime + timedelta = datetime
            return self.ref_datetime + td

    def make_value_from_datastore(self, dt):
        if dt is not None:
            # datetime - datetime = timedelta
            return dt - self.ref_datetime
```

And here's an equivalent implementation for the [NDB API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/), if you're that way inclined:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class TimeDeltaProperty(ndb.DateTimeProperty):
    # Use a reference datetime half way between the min and max possible
    # datetimes, so that we can support both +ve and -ve timedeltas
    ref_datetime = (datetime.max - datetime.min) / 2 + datetime.min

    def _validate(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, timedelta):
            raise TypeError('expected a datetime.timedelta, got %r' % value)

    def _to_base_type(self, value):
        # datetime + timedelta = datetime
        return self.ref_datetime + td

    def _from_base_type(self, value):
        # datetime - datetime = timedelta
        return dt - self.ref_datetime
```

### Accuracy

A `timedelta` in Python can handle deltas of roughly +/-2.7 million years. However, a `datetime` only covers a range of about 10,000 years. To store a greater timedelta in a datetime, you'll have to do some shifting and sacrifice some accuracy.

The approach above limits timedeltas to half this range - about +/-5000 years, because of the choice of reference datetime.

If you know your timedelta will always be positive, you can use `ref_datetime = datetime.min` (or if you know it'll always be negative you can use `ref_datetime = datetime.max`) to get the full range of about 10,000 years.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle
import datetime

...

delta = end_time - start_time
for_storage = pickle.dumps(delta)
#now you have a string representation of your timedelta object that you can store

#sometime later...
delta = pickle.loads(from_storage)
```

You'll still need to convert the delta to a time resolution of your choice using the days, mins, seconds, and microseconds attributes of the time delta.

Comment: yeah, really doing something wrong - tried storing it as a string, that didn't work either:

raise BadValueError('Property %s is not multi-line' % self.name)
10.
BadValueError: Property Duration is not multi-line

Comment: Ouch, no. This will be slow, and the value will be unindexable.

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately worked:

```
delta = StartTime - EndTime

event_record.Duration = int((delta.microseconds)/1000)
```

basically, needed to get microseconds out of the timedelta and convert it to milliseconds.

Comment: Don't do that! timedelta has 3 fields, (days, seconds, microseconds), and you're only considering the microseconds fields. Timedeltas of 0:0:0.5, 0:0:30.5, and 1:2:3.5 will all be recorded identically.