# convert timedelta object to time object

Tags: python, sql

When fetching rows from my database containing time ex 15:15:15 h/m/s.
I get those in timedelta objects, i want them in time object so I later can combine them with a date object and get a datetime object.

```
for row in results:
    startDate = row['startDate']
    StartTime = row['startTime']
    myListStartDate.append(datestart)
    myListTimeStart.append(startTime)
```

When i put all the startTimes in a list and prints the list i get datetime.timedelta(0, 54900). So how do convert the timedelta to a time object so I later can compare it to other time objects.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? [timedelta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190045/how-to-convert-datetime-timedelta-to-minutes-hours-in-python).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> startTime = datetime.timedelta(0, 54915)
>>> startTime = (datetime.datetime.min + startTime).time()
>>> startTime
datetime.time(15, 15, 15)
```

Credit goes to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764184/python-how-do-i-get-time-from-a-datetime-timedelta-object).