# get datetime from date and time

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am looking for a way to plot temperature over datetime. The problem is that I have datetime as date in the format [(datetime.date(2020, 4, 3),), (datetime.date(2020, 4, 3),)] and a corresponding timedelta in the format [(datetime.timedelta(0, 27751),), (datetime.timedelta(0, 27761),)]. A datetime.date / datetime.timedelta object in a tuple in a list. 
Can someone help me to find a propper solution with getting a datetime from the date and the timedelta?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert *timedelta* object to *time* object:
   [convert timedelta object to time object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959604/convert-timedelta-object-to-time-object)
2. And then use *combine* method to receive *datetime* object:
   [Convert date to datetime in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937622/convert-date-to-datetime-in-python)