# Error getting Time from datetime.timedelta object in python

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

I want to retrieve time in the format of "HH:MM" from datetime.timedelta object. I have a table stored in MySQL database. It has time column, which has stored the time in the format,

```
00:00:00
```

I have connected to MySQL server using PyMySQL module,

```
conn = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "cloudera", "streaming")
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "select * from table1 limit 5;"
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
row[1]
```

Output is,

```
datetime.timedelta(0)
```

I have been through this post [Python: How do I get time from a datetime.timedelta object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764184/python-how-do-i-get-time-from-a-datetime-timedelta-object). But the difference from that question and mine is in output result. For that post, output is

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 64800)
```

And for me it is just,

```
datetime.timedelta(0)
```

I just don't get it why the output for me is that way. Can anyone please help me in retrieving time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: timedelta(0) would mean 0 days, 0 seconds, so you would want 00:00

Comment: Oh! But later in the table there are entries like "23:00". So, how would that be addressed from datetime module?

Comment: what is the datatype for this column with "23:00" ?

Comment: paste the output of the following mysql command:  show columns from table1

Comment: `date       | time     | id        | name                | count        |                                                                                         
+------------+----------+-----------+----------------------------+--------------+
| 2009-05-01 | 23:00:00 |         4 | Town Hall (West)           |         1592 `          Datatype for Time given in MySQL is "Time". For this output, output in python is `datetime.timedelta(0, 82800)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type `row[1]` python prints the repr of the variable - in this case repr of a timedelta is "datetime.timedetla(days, seconds)".

You can stringify it using `str` but that would give you HH:MM:SS

```
str(row[1]) 
-> "23:00:00"
```

To get HH:MM you can do the following:

```
(datetime.min + row[1]).strftime("%H:%M")
-> "23:00"
```

So your code should look like this:

```
conn = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "cloudera", "streaming")
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "select * from table1 limit 5;"
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()

timestr = (datetime.min + row[1]).strftime("%H:%M")
print(timestr)
```